# Butterworth filtering and bezier smoothing of a trajectory

Tags: bezier, smoothing, lowpass-filter, butterworth, cubic-bezier

So i have a dataset that represents x-y-z coordinates of a linear motion. The dataset is noisy and i am trying to extract a smooth trajectory as close as possible to the real trajectory using a bezier curve and fitting each point as a control point of the curve. The results are moderately satisfying so i was wondering whether a pre-filtering with a lowpass butterworth will show any better results.

In general is it useful to combine a smoothing technique like bezier or cubic smoothing splines with low pass filtering?

Comment: If you have linear motion, why use an extremely non-linear curve to model it?

Comment: We begin modeling linear motions but in the future we want to make a model that will be applicable to a random motion in 3D space

Comment: Could you maybe explain in more detail how do you compute the control points of the Bezier curve?